# How can I implement in my application something like the additional fields of the field "name" realized in Android contacts?

Tags: android

I want to do something like that, realized in the "add new contact" form

[Additional fields ( details )  of the "name" field in the "add new contact" form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr4MO.png)

[Simplified mode of the field, when additional fields do not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO1Ce.png)

I want to do something like that, so when user clicks on the show\hide button on the right, additional form fields appear. How it works in the native Android contacts? Is it ExpendableListView with adapter, or just a imagebutton with OnClick action that shows additional fields, or something else? How can i do something like that in my application?

**Updated**

Details of my application

I have an xActivity, where user should use a NumberPicker to pick a number of pupils he want to add to the database. After that, application will show to the form that number of "pupil fields", that  user picked before. But each of that pupil fields should have a details, with fields such as "Name", "Surname", "Age", and other.

User can pick a number from 1 to 10.

All that I have now - a NumberPicker, so user can choose a number, but I just want to show other fields to user the best way i can. I like the way Android contacts do it with additional fields, so I think that I can do exactly as realized in my screenshots of Android contacts

Comment: Programming a function that changes visibility of the components you want to hide/show seems the easiest way to do that. What have you coded up to now?

Comment: @jmrodrigg I updated my post with details of my problems. So you can read about what I have already done and what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to achieve the behavior you want to get is described below:

On your `layout.xml`, you will define the `ImageView` that will contain the drawable needed to indicate there are extra fields:

```
​<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:id="@+id/edtName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edtSurname"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edtSurname"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:id="@+id/edtSurname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtSurname"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:id="@+id/edtPhone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edtName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edtName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/edtName"
        android:onClick="expandOptions"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note the `android:onCLick` field on the ImageView. It is telling the method `expandOptions` will be called when clicking the drawable. You should code it in your Activity and, to obtain the behaviour you describe, you may need something like:

```
public void expandOptions(View v) {
    if(isExpanded) {
        edtSurname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edtEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edtPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        edtSurname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        edtEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        edtPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
}
```

This sample is very basic. I am assuming you load all hidden components when your activity starts, but you may prefer to dynamically inflate the extra fields when the user presses the expand button. You may also need to control if fields are required once expanded or not, it is up to you.

Comment: Can i somehow add a selector functional with this solution, when arrow changes it's direction once expanded or not?

Comment: Yes, you can. You may either have a different drawable pointing to the opposite direction or, if you prefer, you can program an animation over your imageview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWCHDoO14aE